# How to resize Bootstrap Modal to Custom Size using React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I'm looking to use Bootstrap's Modal React component on a website.

I would like to manually set the width of the component to be X amount of pixels.

If it is possible to be able to set the css using a const object in the .jsx file that would be prefered! But, if I have to I can use a .css file.

Heres my current React code:

```html
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./profile.css";

class Profile extends React.Component {
  state = {
    show: false
  };

  handleShow = () => {
    this.setState({ show: true });
  };

  handleHide = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.handleShow}>
          Profile
        </Button>

        <Modal
          show={this.state.show}
          onHide={this.handleHide}
          dialogClassName="custom-modal"
          aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title"
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="example-custom-modal-styling-title">
              Custom Modal Styling
            </Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <p>
              Ipsum molestiae natus adipisci modi eligendi? Debitis amet quae
              unde commodi aspernatur enim, consectetur. Cumque deleniti
              temporibus ipsam atque a dolores quisquam quisquam adipisci
              possimus laboriosam. Quibusdam facilis doloribus debitis! Sit
              quasi quod accusamus eos quod. Ab quos consequuntur eaque quo rem!
              Mollitia reiciendis porro quo magni incidunt dolore amet atque
              facilis ipsum deleniti rem!
            </p>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Profile;
```

And here is the css i had:

```css
.custom-modal {
  width: 80% !important;
  height: 1500px !important;
  color: orange;
}
```

And here is the result, as you can see its not the desired width.
[Click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWTAU.png)

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, just was having issues with having "%" signs on the html doc. I instead used "vw" and it fixed my issue!